# Equivalent of SELECT * in NEDB node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nedb

I am new on `nedb` using `node.js` just wondering how to display all records or `SELECT * FROM  tablename` i know that nedb is completely different from mysql but i need to embed a database inside my electron application, i just need to know if nedb is capable of db queries like mysql can do.

The code below able me to find a single records i just want to display all records.

```
var Datastrore = require('nedb');
var db = new Datastrore({filename: 'guitars.db'});



db.loadDatabase(function(err){

 db.find({year : 1990}, function (err,docs){ console.log(docs); });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
db.loadDatabase(function(err){

    db.find({}, function (err,docs){
        console.log(docs);//all docs
    });

});
```